# android app admob clicking your own ads violations downloaded from playstore

Tags: android, click, google-play, admob, ads

I have doubt in admob terms and conditions.,

Consider this is an example.

1. I developed an android application with admob., and published in play store.
2. admob saying that "clicking your own ads will leads to suspension of admob ac"
3. But, I want to use my application. If I do., I definitely see ads and may click on ads. Note: app will be download from playstore. (Not a test app or in develop app).
4. The publisher google ac and app downloader's ac from playsote are same. (It means, I want to download my app from playsote to use).

question 1 : if I click ads in my app downloaded form playstore means it will violating admob terms or not?

Question 2 : if do., How to use my app as user?.,

See., Here I became one of the user like others., I can see my location based ads and if I interested in those ads means I can click those ads know!!!! If I trying to cheat in this case they may don't count my clicks., Because they know this is developer. Why they allow developers to click ads?, They allow then they suspend if dev clicks!!!

I seek expert views about above case., They so rude to me like this is the rules. There is no discussion here. If you are not agree get out from admob.

One more answer was, If you are skill enough developer means you can manage this terms., else you are not. (How to scale skills!!!!)

Another one was, You can download your app and can see your ads., If you are click ads actually or accidentally leads to suspension of admob ac in the middle and lose your balance and ac. I don't knw how it works when come to practicality?

I have read all reviews here and some forums. But I didn't find exact admob/adsence alternatives in india right now., Can you please suggest any admob/adsence alternatives right now (sep 2015).

Comment: thanks., user2413972. But how to add device in "device developer"?. Can you explain clearly? I don't find anything about this in developer.android.com. If you do, It ll be great.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of an ad network, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

1)For sure it will violate admob terms. They will realize it quickly and suspend your account. In some cases they will ban it immediately. Worse, they will get back your earnings back and refund them to ad-givers.

2) You can use your app like that:

-Remove your ad

-Build your app again

-Load that app that has no ad to your device.

Unfortunately there is no other way to do it.

P.s: There are tons of horror stories about whom clicks the ads on their own apps

Answer (score 1):

For once you will not banned. But in general, the solution is simple: add your device in the "Device Developer" or try not to click on ads.